# touch previous props with React.useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

Now I am refactoring `class` component to `function`.

here is my `class` component that should be `function`.

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  //...
  componentDidUpdate({ info: prevInfo }){
    const { info } = this.props;
    if(info.id !== prevInfo.id){
      //Do Something...
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

```js
function App(props){
  //...
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    //I have no idea how could I touch previous props.
    if(props.info !== props.prevInfo){
      //...
    }
  },[props.info]);
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `usePrevious` hook (https://usehooks.com/usePrevious) to get previous value.

Although, if you only want to do something after `props.info.id` was changed then the better way would be to use it as dependency for `useEffect` like that:

```
function App(props) {
  //...
  React.useEffect(() => {
     // Now you know for sure that id changed from previous one
     // because it is used inside dependency array for useEffect
     // and useEffect will only be invoked on first mount or after any of dependency was changed
  }, [props.info.id]);
  //...
}
```